# Set span text based on group of show/hide span tags/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a group of Span tags within a Div that show our hide based on a select. For example:

```
<select id="country" >
<option value="please select"> Please Select </option>
<option value="us"> US </option>
<option value="uk"> UK </option>
```

```
<div id=span-group> <span class="uk">$5.00</span <span class="uk">25 Pounds</span> </div>
```

The script to show and hide these tags works fine...but later in the form process I need to reuse the value that was unhidden in "span-group". For example:

```
<span id="reuse">It looks like you would like to spend **<span *set the text here to match  the unhidden span tag in "span-group"*> </span>**
```

This would be great if there was a way to do this via javascript/jquery since my select group has dozens of options and potential values in the"span-group". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter visible span elements using `:visible` selector:

```
$('#span-group').find('span:visible');
```

Then you can use `each` method for iterating through the selected elements:

```
var a = 0;
$('#span-group').find('span:visible').each(function(){
     a += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
});

$('#reuse').text('...' + a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Jquery visible selector, http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/.

Since only one is going to be visible, you can rely on the visible selector to return the needed element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#reuse span").text($("#span-group span:visible").text());
```

There are multiple `#span-group span` elements.  This assumes that you just want the text of all of them concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that keeps the "reuse" text in sync with "span-group".

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>     
</head>
<body>
    <select id="country">
        <option value="please select"> Please Select </option>
        <option value="us">US</option>
        <option value="uk">UK</option>
    </select>

    <div id="span-group">
        <span class="us">$5.00</span>
        <span class="uk">25 Pounds</span>
    </div>

    <span id="reuse">It looks like you would like to spend <span id="selectedCurrency"></span>

    <script type="text/javascript">                     

        $(function() {
            showSelectedCurrency();

            $('#country').change(function() {
                showSelectedCurrency();
            });             
        }); 

        function showSelectedCurrency() {
            var spanToShow = $('#span-group span.' + $('#country').val());
            $('#span-group span').hide();

            if(spanToShow.length > 0) {
                spanToShow.show();
                $('#selectedCurrency').text(spanToShow.text());
            }
        }
    </script>
    </script>
</body>
```

If you don't want "span-group" and "reuse" to constantly stay in sync but you just want to update "reuse" at some point, you could use the :visible selector as Mr. Vega suggested - something like this:

```
$('#selectedCurrency').text($('#span-group span:visible').text());
```